# Two actions of $U(\mathfrak{h})$ on $U(\mathfrak{g})$ where $\mathfrak{h}\hookrightarrow\mathfrak{g}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{h}$ be a Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}$, then by PBW theorem we know $U(\mathfrak{h})\hookrightarrow U(\mathfrak{g})$.

Let $\{x_i, y_i\}$ be an ordered basis of $\mathfrak{g}$ where $\{x_i\}$ is a basis of $\mathfrak{h}$. Then $\{1, x_{i_1}\cdots x_{i_k}y_{j_1}\cdots y_{j_m}\}$, where $i_1\le \cdots \le i_k$ and $j_1\le \cdots\le j_m$, forms a PBW basis of $U(\mathfrak{g})$.

Since $U(\mathfrak{h})$ is a subalgebra of $U(\mathfrak{g})$, we can define left or right action of $U(\mathfrak{h})$ on $U(\mathfrak{g})$ by left or right multiplication. And PBW tells us that this action makes $U(\mathfrak{g})$ a free left (or right) $U(\mathfrak{h})$-module. Let us call this **action 1**.

Let **action 2** be induced by:
$$x_{i_1}\cdots x_{i_k}\cdot (x_{j_1}\cdots x_{j_l}y_{m_1}\cdots y_{m_n}) = sort(x_{i_1}\cdots x_{i_k}\cdot x_{j_1}\cdots x_{j_l})y_{m_1}\cdots y_{m_n}$$
We can define the right action similarly, and it coincide with left action because we sort the basis elements by order. Also by PBW we can observe that action 2 makes $U(\mathfrak{g})$ a free left (or right) $U(\mathfrak{h})$-module, with the same free basis as was with action 1.

So does it follow that the two $U(\mathfrak{h})$-module structure on $U(\mathfrak{g})$ are isomorphic?

Comment: What does the sort function do? The first reaction would be that for example, $sort(x_1x_3x_2)=x_1x_2x_3$, but that won't give a $U(\mathfrak{h})$-module action or?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your action 2 is not even well-defined if $\mathfrak{h}$ is not commutative:

Let $i<j$ such that $[x_i,x_j]\neq0$. Then
$$(x_ix_j)\cdot1=x_ix_j=(x_jx_i)\cdot1,$$
hence:
$$0\neq[x_i,x_j]=[x_i,x_j]\cdot1=(x_ix_j-x_jx_i)\cdot1=0,$$
which is impossible.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Ok, so $U(\mathfrak{g})$ won't be a free $U(\mathfrak{h})$-module, but this action is still valid correct?

Comment: @mez I've edited my answer to show why your action is not well-defined when $\mathfrak{h}$ is not commutative.

Comment: But why can't $(x_ix_j-x_jx_i)\cdot 1 = 0$?

Comment: @mez because I chose $x_i$ and $x_j$ such that $[x_i,x_j]\neq0$. Look at the line:$$0\neq[x_i,x_j]=[x_i,x_j]\cdot1=(x_ix_j-x_jx_i)\cdot1=0.$$ All the $=$'s and $\neq$'s in there should really make sense. If you have a question about one specific term in there, feel free to ask for clarification.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf why does $[x_i,x_j]=[x_i,x_j]\cdot 1$? I think that by his definition you should compute $[x_i,x_j]\cdot \alpha = (x_ix_j)\cdot\alpha + (x_jx_i)\cdot \alpha$, for every $\alpha\in U(\mathfrak g)$. Hence, I think you can't say that $[x_i,x_j]\cdot 1=[x_i,x_j]$.

Comment: @JúlioCésar $[x_i,x_j]\in\mathfrak{h}$, so by his very definition: $$[x_i,x_j]\cdot1=\text{sort}\bigl([x_i,x_j]\bigr)1=[x_i,x_j]1=[x_i,x_j].$$

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I think you might be right, but by the way 'mez' wrote the definition I understood (and I might be wrong) that 'sort' is a function from the set of monomials (in x_i's) to the set of monomials. Anyway, I agree that $\mathfrak h$ must be abelian because you can restrict the action of $U(\mathfrak h)$ to a representation of $\mathfrak h$ and a argument similar to the one you gave in your answer applies.

Comment: @JúlioCésar I think we both understood the same definition for mez's action; but here, $[x_i,x_j]\in\mathfrak{h}$ so can be written as a linear combination of elements of $\mathfrak{h}$, say $[x_i,x_j]=\sum_k\alpha_kx_k$. Now each $x_k$ acts on $1$ as $x_k\cdot1=x_k$, so, really $[x_i,x_j]\cdot1=[x_i,x_j]$. I don't really understand where I could be wrong here, maybe am I missing something?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Now, I totally agree with you. If your point was the linearity since the begining I am sorry that I have missed it and bothered you.